# Linq query how to select last one week data from today's date

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

How to select week data (last 7 days data) from the current date using LINQ,

What I have tried is ,I am not really sure if what I written is correct or wrong

```
var QueryDeatils = from M in db.Tr_Mealcode
                   where M.codeDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7)
                   group M by M.merchantID into G
                   select new
                   {
                      MerchantId=G.Select(m=>m.merchantID)
                   };
```

After trying this I got an exception

```
The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. 
Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var dateCriteria = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
var QueryDeatils = from M in db.Tr_Mealcode
                   where M.codeDate >= dateCriteria 
                   group M by M.merchantID into G
                   select new
                   {
                      MerchantId=G.Select(m=>m.merchantID)
                   };
```

Comment: but it is still giving me the same exception

Comment: Maybe something was wring with the schema, cause this example works perfectly